# Beautiful soup. Scraping multiple urls with Python3

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

When I run the following code...

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

counter = []
url = 'https://www.somemuseum.org/exhibitions/current-exhibitions'
req = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')
links = soup.find_all(href="{{ card.url }}")
counter.append(links)
print(counter)
```

It returns...

```
<a class="card card--exhibit {{ card.type }}" href="{{ card.url }}">
```

Inspecting the same element on the site shows it stored as...

```
<a href="/exhibitions/listings/2018/current-listing" class="card card--exhibit is-tier1">
```

What I'd like to do is a `for loop` similar to the following...

```
for link in links:
    if card.type=="is-tier1":
        exhibit = soup.get('card.url')
        counter.append(exhibit)
```

I'm new to Beautiful Soup so any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't get the href data with BeautifulSoup, because they are rendered by js. However, you have a couple of options.

The first option is [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/).
Selenium runs js and has methods to select html elements, but it's quite slow and heavy.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


url = "https://www.metmuseum.org/exhibitions/current-exhibitions"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.card')))
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('a.is-tier1')
links = [e.get_attribute("href") for e in elements]
driver.quit()
```

---

The second option is to use the api.
The data are loaded by xhr request to `/api/Exhibitions/CurrentExhibitionsListing`. You could request the data directly from the api, and get the results in json format.

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.metmuseum.org/api/Exhibitions/CurrentExhibitionsListing?location=main|breuer|cloisters&page=1'
req = requests.get(url)
results = req.json()['results']
links = [
    'https://www.metmuseum.org' + i['url'] 
    for i in results if i['type'] == 'is-tier1'
    ]
```

Both methods produce the same results, but i'd use the second as it's much faster.

Comment: Thank you. This works perfectly. Just curious to know, where did you find the API link for the Met? I didn't see this listed upon initial inspection of their site.

Comment: Yes, sorry, i forgot to mention that. As far as i know it's not a public api. I discovered it by inspacting the network traffic in my browser.